# Locale selection for searching and sorting in web app

Tags: database, internationalization, localization

In a web app i'm working on, there's some i18n/l10n support. Some entities (I'm using locations as an example) support having names in multiple locales. The app has a `primary_locale` (defaulting to 'en' if unspecified) as well as an `other_locales` setting.

Besides that, each user also has a locale setting (again defaulting to 'en').

There is a list view, and it is required to be able to search for locations by name, as well as sort them by name in that view.

What i'm having issues with is selecting a single locale for the searching and sorting, since:

- the user locale setting might not match the app primary locale setting, and hence, location names might not be in the user's selected (or defaulted) locale
- there is no way to set the locale for the sorting or searching from the user interface.

Comment: IMHO your question is unclear - your did not tell us precisely *why* the user's locale cannot be used for sorting.

Comment: the way the question is worded, sounds like the application you are working on lacks a method to determine the effective locale of the user